# Resolving manual references on a large MongoDB document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

What would be the best strategy to resolve manual references in a large (millions of records) mongodb document?

I have a mostly denormalized document but containing a few normalized fields using manual references such as in this example:

```
db.test.insert({ _id: ObjectId('5447e59575a404a81e34df01'), name: 'Hockey', teamSport: true })
db.test.insert({ _id: ObjectId('5446648ea1851287e7090c25'), name: 'Reading' })
db.test.insert({ _id: ObjectId('5447e59575a404a81e34df0a'), name: 'Taxidermy' })

db.test.insert({ _id: ObjectId('5447e59575a404a81e34df02'), name: 'Alfred', hobbies: [ObjectId('5447e59575a404a81e34df01'), ObjectId('5446648ea1851287e7090c25')] })
db.test.insert({ _id: ObjectId('5447e59575a404a81e34df07'), name: 'Boris', hobbies: [ObjectId('5446648ea1851287e7090c25')] })
db.test.insert({ _id: ObjectId('5447e5b175a404a81e34fa66'), name: 'Cheng', hobbies: [ObjectId('5446648ea1851287e7090c25'), ObjectId('5447e59575a404a81e34df0a')] })
```

Considering the data above I want to search for people who practice team sports and the result should be 'Alfred'.

I am considering creating "temporary" tables to store the projection of results for each intermediate step of a given query query (in this case, the ObjectIds of records where teamSport is true) as a form to cache them.

Is there a better way to resolve manual references in a large document either by using Mongo operators or by using the C# driver?

Comment: How big are the intermediate results here? You could use a large `$in` query, which are fine with proper indexes as long as the number of `$in` values is on the order of thousands, not tens or hundreds of thousands. Depending on how critical these queries are to your use case, you might consider a different data model.

Comment: @wdberkeley the intermediate results are on the order of thousands. The problem I'll have on further denormalizing my model is that updates will become expensive due to the number of "duplicated" embedded documents.